# print on stdout RSA public key using openssl

Tags: c, unix, openssl, rsa

how can i print public key stored in a const unsigned char * after extract with i2d_RSAPublicKey ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather broad. However, assuming that the public key is an array of `unsigned char`, you will need to convert each char (each byte) into something readable, such as hexadecimal or base-64 encoding.

Something as simple as printing the entire key in hexadecimal might work:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < pubkey_len;  i++)
    printf("%02X", pubkey[i]);
```