# send RSA public key by socket

Tags: c, unix, openssl, rsa

I'm using openssl libraryes on client/server application, and i need to share public key with client.
this is the struct of packet:

```
typedef struct pack {
    char op[10];
    char message[1024];
    int id;
}packet;
```

and this is how extract the public key and put it in message field:

```
packet *send_pack
RSA *rsa,
const unsigned char *my_public_key;

my_public_key = malloc(1024);
send_pack = (packet*) malloc(sizeof (packet));
rsa = RSA_new();
rsa = RSA_generate_key(1024, 17, NULL, NULL);
i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsa, &my_public_key);
printf("my public key: %X\n", (unsigned int)my_public_key);
strcpy(send_pack->message, my_public_key);
printf("field message of send pack %X", (unsigned int)send_pack->message );

...
```

but the two printf print two similar value, but not the same (for example the first printf return A0B9092 and the second A0B944 ).
What's wrong ?

Comment: It's interesting to point out you're still printing the key wrong after you got an answer yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096825/print-on-stdout-rsa-public-key-using-openssl

Comment: ops, i've paste the wrong version of printing code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- You're printing pointer addresses instead of contents
- You're copying the key wrong since `strcpy` expects 0-terminated strings

For the first issue, you should note `i2d_RSAPublicKey` returns a length which you're ignoring. So you should print:

```
int len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(...);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("%02x", my_public_key[i]);
```

For the second part, use `memcpy` instead:

```
memcpy(send_pack->message, my_public_key, len);
```